# Solving simultaneous multivariate polynomial equations with python

Tags: python, math, scipy, polynomial-math, sympy

*edit: the reference I got my equations from contained a couple of errors. I've fixed it here. Solutions might actually make sense now!*

When a two layer fluid flows over topography, there exist a number
of different solutions depending on the relative size of the flow
speed and the wave speed in the fluid.

[image: critical-flow]

These are termed 'supercritical', 'subcritical' and 'critical' (the
first two I refer to here as 'extra-critical').

The following equations define the bounding lines between critical
and extra-critical behaviour in (h, U0) parameter space:

[image: eq1]

[image: eq2]

I want to eliminate `d_1c` (i.e. I don't care what it is) and find
solutions to these equations in `(h, U_0)`.

Simplifying factors:

- I only need answers for *given* `d_0`
- *I do not need exact solutions*, just an outline of the solution
  curves, so this can be solved either analytically or numerically.
- I only want to plot over the region (h, U0) = (0,0) to (0.5, 1).

I'd like to solve this using modules available in the Enthought
distribuion (numpy, scipy, sympy), but really don't know where to
start. It's the elimination of the variable d1c that really confuses
me.

Here are the equations in python:

```py
def eq1(h, U0, d1c, d0=0.1):
    f = (U0) ** 2 * ((d0 ** 2 / d1c ** 3) + (1 - d0) ** 2 / (1 - d1c - d0) ** 3) - 1
    return f

def eq2(h, U0, d1c, d0=0.1):
    f = 0.5 * (U0) ** 2 * ((d0 ** 2 / d1c ** 2) - (1 - d0) ** 2 / (1 - d1c - d0) ** 2) + d1c + (h - d_0)
    return f
```

I'm expecting a solution that has a number of solution branches (not
always physical, but don't worry about that) and looks roughly
like this:

[image: critical-regime-diagram]

How do I go about implementing this?

Comment: I recommend asking this over on scicomp.stackexchange.com . I suspect that the expertise there is more aligned with your domain.

Comment: Can you be more specific what you mean by "eliminate dlc"? Are you saying it should cancel completely from the final solution?

Comment: I mean that I don't need to know d1c. I was thinking I had two equations in 4 variables (U0, h, d1c, d0) and if I set one (d0) and eliminate another (d1c), I'd be left with two equations in (U0, h) allowing me to find solutions expressed as a relation between U0 and h.

Comment: This question is cross-posted: http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/4843/solving-simultaneous-multivariate-polynomial-equations-with-python

Comment: i've removed the scicomp question. will stick it out on SO for a while longer.

Comment: Actually, I think cross-posting to other SE sites is discouraged. If you want, you could probably move the question there, though.

Answer (score 4):

Semi-formally, the problem you are trying to solve is the following: given d0, solve the logical formula "there exists d1c such that eq1(h, U0, d1c, d0) = eq2(h, U0, d1c, d0) = 0" for h and U0.

There exists an algorithm to reduce the formula to a polynomial equation "P(h, U0) = 0", it's called "quantifier elimination" and it usually relies on another algorithm, "cylindrical algebraic decomposition". Unfortunately, this isn't implemented in sympy (yet).

However, since U0 can easily be eliminated, there are things you can do with sympy to find your answer. Start with

```
h, U0, d1c, d0 = symbols('h, U0, d1c, d0')
f1 = (U0) ** 2 * ((d0 ** 2 / d1c ** 3) + (1 - d0) ** 2 / (1 - d1c - d0 * h) ** 3) - 1
f2 = U0**2 / 2 * ((d0 ** 2 / d1c ** 2) + (1 - d0) ** 2 / (1 - d1c - d0 * h)) + d1c + d0 * (h - 1)
```

Now, eliminate U0 from f1 and insert the value in f2 (I'm doing it "by hand" rather than with solve() to get a prettier expression):

```
U2_val = ((f1 + 1)/U0**2)**-1
f3 = f2.subs(U0**2, U2_val)
```

f3 only depends on h and d1c. Also, since it's a rational fraction, we only care about when its numerator goes to 0, so we get a single polynomial equation in 2 variables:

```
p3 = fraction(cancel(f3))
```

Now, for a given d0, you should be able to invert p3.subs(d0, .1) numerically to get h(d1c), plug it back into U0 and make a parametric plot of (h, U0) as a function of d1c.

Answer (score 3):

Let me deal with elimination of `d1c` first. Imagine you managed to massage the first equation to have the form `d1c = f(U, h, d0)`. Then you would substitute this into the second equation, and have a certain relation between `U`, `h` and `d0`. With `d0` fixed, this defines a single equation for two variables, `U` and `h`, from which you can, in principle, find `U` for any given `h`. Which seems to be what you are calling solutions, based on your last sketch. 
Bad news is that it's not easy to get `d1c` from either of your equations. Good news is that you don't need to.

`fsolve` can take a system of equations, say two equations which depend on two variables and give you the solution. In this case: fix `h` (`d0` is fixed already), and feed to `fsolve` the system you have, treating as variables `U0` and `d1c`. Record the value of `U0`, repeat for next value of `h`, and so on.

Notice that, contrary to the suggestion of  @duffymo, I'd recommend using `fsolve`, or, at least start with it, and look for other solvers only if it runs out of steam.

A possible caveat is that you are expecting to have more than one solution for `U0` given `h`: `fsolve` needs a starting guess, and there's no easy way of telling it to converge to one of the solution branches. If that turns out to be a problem, look at `brentq` solver.

A different way would be to observe that you can easily eliminate `U0` from your system. This way you'll get a single equation for `h` and `d1c`, solve it for `d1c` for each value of `h`, and then use either of your original equations to calculate `U0` given `d1c` and `h`.

An example of using `fsolve`:

```
>>> from scipy.optimize import fsolve
>>> def f(x, p):
...   return x**2 -p
... 
>>> fsolve(f, 0.5, args=(2,))
array([ 1.41421356])
>>>
```

Here `args=(2,)` is the syntax for telling `fsolve` that what you actually want to solve if `f(x,2)=0`, and `0.5` is the starting guess for the value of `x`.

Answer (score 0):

You use non-linear solvers like Newton Raphson or BFGS to solve simultaneous, non-linear equations.  They're sensitive to starting conditions and conditioning of the matricies, so some care will be needed.

Comment: If you multiply through by the denominators, are they not polynomials? Or are they actually non-linear polynomials?

Comment: Any polynomial of order greater than one is non-linear, by definition.  I see a dc1^2 term, so that's second order.